# XSL Add Attribute (not namespace) to XML root while copy whole document

Tags: xml, xslt

can anyone tell me a better solution to add an attribute to xml root, while copying the whole xml.

Simple XML Structure to explain the task

```
<MYROOT test1="someattribute1" test2="someattribute2">
<SOMEDATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
</SOMEDATA>
</MYROOT>
```

requested solution

actual solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="rootname" select="local-name(*)"/>

        <xsl:element name="{($rootname)}">
            <xsl:attribute name="staticobject" select="'true'"/>

            <xsl:copy-of select="//*/node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

actual result

```
<MYROOT staticobject="true">
<SOMEDATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
</SOMEDATA>
</MYROOT>
```

expected result

```
<MYROOT test1="someattribute1" test2="someattribute2" staticobject="true">
<SOMEDATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
<DATA>...</DATA>
</SOMEDATA>
</MYROOT>
```

Can anyone tell me a better solution?
With this solution i will lost all other attributes from root, when they exist.

I Like only to add attribute to xml, while coping the whole xml document.

It must be a better solution so solve that.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the root element then write a template for that:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="staticobject" select="'true'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In general it might be better to use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` and add the identity transformation template as then you can add more templates for other changes easily.

Comment: working great. so simple, so eay, so greatfull. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="staticobject" select="'true'"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```